# try catch statments with in a class and controller

Tags: php, laravel, try-catch

I have a question about try catch bock exceptions. I want to know if I have a class called Image that makes images and in that class is a try catch statement and if there is an error I want my controller that makes the image to return the response, So in my controller I also have a catch statement what I want to know is what I have below correct and going to work when I have an error and if it aint going to work can you show me how my statements should be.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Acme\Imaging;

use Image as Intervention;

class Image
{

    public function __construct($input) {

    }

    public function save() {
        try {

            $image = Intervention::make(...);
            $image->save(...);

        } catch(NotReadableException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => true, 'message' => $e->getMessage()], $e->getCode(), ['Content-Length' =>$e->getMessage()])
        }
    }
}

public function store(PostRequest $request)
{
    try {
        $image = new Image;
        $image->width = 500;
        $image->height = 500;
        $image->save();

        $post = new Post;
        $post->fill($request->all());
        $post->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
        $post->image = $image;

        if($post->save()) {
            return response()->json($post, 200, ['Content-Lnegth' => strlen(json_encode($post))]);
        }

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(array('error' => true, 'type' => 'exception', 'message' => $e->getMessage()), $e->getCode(), ['Content-Length' => strlen($e->getMessage())]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `NotReadableException` referrers to an extended class `Exception` that you must create in order to do that: nothing is wrong with the `try{} catch() {}` block. I'm unsure where `response()` is coming from however. You sure it isn't `$e->response()` ? Since `$e` is the instanced Exception

Comment: If I do $e->response([], $e->getCode(), ['Content-Length' => $e->getMessage()]) is that going to return in json because that's what I wanting

Comment: Acutally could you show me what you mean by creating an NotReadableException class can you give me an answer please show me how to link it all together @KDOT

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not throwing the error, the controller will not catch it. In order to maintain the original error data, You could do something like this...

```
public function save() {
    try {

        $image = Intervention::make(...);
        $image->save(...);

    } catch(NotReadableException $e) {
        throw new Exception('Error Saving file: ' . 'message: ' . e->getMessage() . ' code: ' . $e->getCode();
    }
}
```

Then your calling function will enter the catch block and spit out the whole thing as part of it's $e->getMessage()

Comment: So if i throw an error in the try block will my controller catch the error and return it as json

Comment: I am not sure exactly how your controller is setup, but typically you would still need to encode your response in json, but are you trying to pass it to a view or an ajax request, etc?  I was assuming that your store function was in the controller, is that true?

Answer (score 0):

```
[...]

} catch( NotReadableException $e ) {
    return json_encode( array(
        'code'           => $e
            ->response()
            ->getCode(),
        'content-length' => $e
            ->response()
            ->getMessage()
    ) );
}

[...]
```

To encode something in json, you must use the `json_encode()` function. Assuming that the instanced `NotReadableException` is using the `response()` method to return an object holding the data, it may look something like the above.

`response()` indicates the current objects scope, you need to target the instanced Exception through the variable you created (`$e`), however, you have shown no code for that so I can only guess your hierarchy of it.

---

The below example on a non-extended `Exception` class looks like this:

```
try {
    throw new Exception( "Example message." );
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    return json_encode( array (
        'content-length' => $e
            ->getMessage()
    ) );
}
```

---

**[See it working here](https://3v4l.org/O7WJF) over at https://3v4l.org/O7WJF.**